# Python reference external module in Netbeans

Tags: python, netbeans, module, projects

I'm working with a Netbeans for Python development, I have a number of projects (which have a number of modules). What I basically want to know is, how do I import one of these modules into a new project? I have tried editing the python path in netbeans, but to no avail. Here's my setup:

```
Netbeans projects
=================
ProjectA
   ModuleA
       ClassA.py (Assume a class called TestClass exists in this file)
   ModuleB
       ...
ProjectB
   ...
ProjectC
   ...
```

Now what I want to do is in a "new project" is the following:

```
from ProjectA.ModuleA.ClassA import TestClass
```

Do I have to add the src folders for each of the projects to the pythonpath? I
have tried this but still I get "No Module named ..."

Comment: +1 for a common Python question people bump into with modern IDEs.

Answer (score 2):

Hadji, you may want to discard Netbeans' default structures for Python development.

First of all, Python code file (`.py`) is a module. A package contains a number of modules.

What you should do is structure your files like the following:

```
Netbeans projects
=================
PackageA
   __init__.py (This file is crucial for Python to recognise the folder as a package.)
   ClassA.py (Assume a class called TestClass exists in this file)
   ...
PackageB
   ...
PackageC
   ...
```

Then, in your `ProjectC` (which is now basically a folder), you can do

```
from PackageA.ClassA import TestClass
```

Again, please remember a Python module is a `.py` file. You also don't need the `src` folder, and all of your modules should be inside appropriate packages. =]

**More references:**

[Filesystem structure of a Python project](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html)